# deploying a specific git version of a gem into passenger via rvm global gemset

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, passenger, gemset

We've a deploy issue I'm having with passenger using a specific github
version of the handsoap gem, which is specified in the Gemfile.

bundle states:

```
Using handsoap (1.1.8) from git://github.com/unwire/handsoap.git (at e6f79ec)

[ rubyapp]$ bundle show handsoap
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bundler/gems/handsoap-e6f79ec9d6a3

[ rubyapp]$ bundle show capybara
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/capybara-1.1.3
```

(There's many other gems but I thought I'd add capybara to show where they are. There's no other specific github versioned gems)

Sadly we've not got root access to change to another gemset - i.e. not
global and it was installed before the project was setup, so we were not able to specify a custom gemset before, as you would in the local development environment. This version of the gem is needed unfortunately.

Passenger reports:

> git://github.com/unwire/handsoap.git (at e6f79ec) is not checked out.
>   Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)

I've tried a `gemset empty global` , and a following `bundle install`
I've tried a `gemset empty global` , and a following `bundle install`
I've tried
`rm /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bundler/gems/handsoap-e6f79ec9d6a3`
and a `bundle install`

all which give the same passenger error as specified above.

Any help would be appreciated. The application has been working previously within the global gemset - but with a previous version of handsoap, but now it's time for a new deploy of the code.

Spent a couple of hours now trying out different options.

Cheers in advance,
Ian.